# Dialogflow: Forcing certain intents to be invalid given context

Tags: android-intent, response, dialogflow-es

I want to make knock knock jokes using dialogflow, but I found that I can trigger one knock knock joke from the context of another. For example I have the following intents:

- knockknock: training phrase (knock knock joke), response (knock knock)

  - whosethere: trainging phrase (who dat), response (annie, orange)

    - punchline-annie: training phrase (annie who), response (annie thing you can do I can do better)
    - punchline-orange: training phrase (orange who), response (orange you glad...)

If the bot responds with annie, I can respond with orange who and get the orange punchline to the joke. How can I prevent this from happening? I only want the orange punchline to be able to be called when the response from the whosethere intent was orange.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if we had some code sample(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to look into how to send a responsive via fulfilment/webhook and how contexts work. In your whosthere intent, you could send a response via fulfilment and set the context appropriately. E.g.: if you answer with "annie", set an annie specific context (e.g. punchline-annie-context) and set punchline-annie-context as an input context for the punchline-annie intent. This way you ensure that punchline-annie can only be activated, if the whosthere response was "annie".

Comment: Thank you, I will look into using fulfilments/webhooks.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @andreas030241 for the information. I figured out how to get the logic to work by learning how to use fulfillment. I set the response of the knockknock-whosethere intent inside the inline editor, and created an associated context name, that I then used as the input context for whichever punchline intent I wanted to be valid. The example code is below. Much appreciation!

```
  function punchline(agent) {
    var names = [`Annie`,`Orange`,`Lena`,`Quiche`,`Wa`,`A little old lady`];
    var context_names = ['annie-punchline','orange-punchline','lena-punchline','quiche-punchline','wa-punchline','alittleoldlady-punchline'];
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
    agent.add(names[number]);
    agent.setContext({
        name: context_names[number],
        lifespan: 1,
        });
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('knockknock-whosethere', punchline);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```